# Сохранение json файла в локальную сеть с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, json, файлы

Мой вопрос очень похож на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666846/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-json-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-node-js).

Есть файл с информацией в .json, который хранится рядом с main.html. В main.html я написал редактор этого json.

Идея в том, что я скачиваю у себя свой же файл (простите, проще не нашёл, буду рад за помощь), изменяю его в редакторе, а потом опять перезаписываю этот же файл.

Скачивание и обработка:

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
        var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xobj.overrideMimeType("application/text");
        xobj.open('GET', '../data.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
        xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
                callback(xobj.responseText);
              }
        };
        xobj.send(null);
      }

      document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',function() {
        // Get the value from the editor
        var userJson = editor.getValue();
        console.log("userJson:", userJson);

        loadJSON(function(response) {
            var previousJson = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log("previousJson:", previousJson);

            var newJson = previousJson;

            var days = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"];
            var i = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
              newJson[userJson["Класс"] + "_lessons"][i] = userJson[days[i]];
            }

            console.log("newJson:", newJson)

            // тут должно быть сохранение

        });
      });
```

Проблема в том, что я не умею перезаписывать.

То есть: есть переменная *newJson*, которую надо вывести в файл "*../data.json*". Что мне надо сделать?

Comment: Сделайте свой вопрос похожим на тот. Я пока сильно сомневаюсь что у вас вообще сервер запущен.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, пока я просто открываю html страницу localhost на своем компе, потом перекину

Comment: Глобально ответ на ваш вопрос это посылать обратно на сервер json как string - `JSON.stringify(data)`, на сервере принимать ее и `fs.writeFile`

Comment: Как то не понятно? вы знаете язык `php`?

Comment: Где ваш код? пусть не рабочий, дайте то что вы уже сделали

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, простите. Понял, что написал полную дичь. Исправил вопрос

Comment: @StackOverflow, поправил вопрос.

Comment: Нечего не поправили

Comment: @StackOverflow, добавил код, простите за то, что он ужасен

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70937/discussion-between-stack-overflow-and--).

Comment: Нормальный код! Только это можно на джаваскрипте и заставить работать без браузера, используя node.js